# How do I reference the root object in a groovy template?

Tags: java, groovy

I want to create a groovy template where it iterates over the root map, but I do not know how to reference the map.

For example if I pass in a map

```
def map = [a: 1, b:2]
```

with a template (where ??? would be the root element)

```
<% ???.each { %>
"name": "it.key", "value": "it.value"
<% } %>
```

Is there a way to reference this root object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `binding.variables`.  Example:

```
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

def template = new SimpleTemplateEngine().createTemplate('''
<% binding.variables.each { key, value -> %>
name = $key, value = $value
<% } %>
''')
def out = template.make([hello: 'world'])
println out.toString()
```

Comment: That will work since the initial map seems to have been eaten up and this is all you get left.  Ill just have to remember to exclude out when I use it.